# Inline XSLT syntax used in Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt

I'd like to parse a SOAPUI Project file and generate some documentation from the file. I've written an XSLT to parse the project (my plan being that I run a scheduled job using Msxsl to automatically generate the latest "documentation" for my smoke tests).

The problem >>
 my xml files will contain multiple projects and within those projects there are lists of test cases. I'd ideally like to wrap those test cases in a collapsible div so that the overall document is more readable. Currently my div is being created and I'm trying to give it a unique name using the position of the Testsuite node.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

  <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:con="http://eviware.com/soapui/config">
    <xsl:output method="html" encoding ="utf-8"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
      <html>
        <head>
          <script language="javascript">
            function toggleDiv(divid){
            if(document.getElementById(divid).style.display == 'none')
              {
                document.getElementById(divid).style.display = 'block';
              }
            else
              {
                 document.getElementById(divid).style.display = 'none';
              }
            }
          </script>

          <style type="text/css">
            body {font-family:Arial,Helvetica; }

            h1 {color:black;
            font-size:0.975em;

            }

            h2.ex {color:black;
            font-size:0.875em;


            }

            li.tc {
            font-size:0.875em;
            }

            p.desc {
            margin: 2%;
            border: 1px dotted black;
            font-size:0.775em;
            line-height:90%
            }


          </style>
        </head>
        <body>

          <xsl:apply-templates/>

        </body>
      </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="con:soapui-project">
      <h1>
        Project Name:<xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
      </h1>
      <br />
      <xsl:apply-templates/>

    </xsl:template>



    <xsl:template match="con:testSuite">
      <hr></hr>

      <a href="javascript:;" onmousedown="toggleDiv('<xsl:value-of select="position()"/>');">
        <xsl:attribute name="onmousedown"><xsl:value-of select="position()"/></xsl:attribute> 
        <h2 class="ex">
          TestSuite:      <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
        </h2>
      </a>
      <br>
        <p class="desc">
          Description: <xsl:value-of select="con:description"/>

        </p>
      </br>

      <br />
      <div id="mydiv" style="display:none">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
      </div>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="con:testCase">

        <ul>
          <li class="tc">
            (#<xsl:value-of select="position()-3"/>) Testcase:      <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
          </li>

          <xsl:if test="con:description=''">
            (RICHARD - PLEASE PROVIDE A DESCRIPTION!!)
          </xsl:if>

          <p class="desc">
            Description: <xsl:value-of select="con:description"/>
          </p>
        </ul>
        <xsl:apply-templates />

    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="*"></xsl:template>


  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

This currently fails because of a validation error when I try to put XSLT syntax into the Javascript. I feel like I'm close, but usual escape methods aren't working for me.

Can someone offer the final piece?

Cheers,
- Richard

Comment: Minor aside, but the language for the script is usually specified with `type="text/javascript"`. Strictly speaking it should be `application/javascript`, but that's not supported by some browsers.

Comment: Your stylesheet has some problems. But validation is the first: this start tag `<a href="javascript:;" onmousedown="toggleDiv('<xsl:value-of select="position()"/>');">` is not valid, you must escape `<` in attribute value. You could use an Attribute Value Template: `<a href="javascript:;" onmousedown="toggleDiv('{position()}');">`

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer that points out an obvious problem with your code and provides the standard solution.

Comment: Thanks Alejandro. Both yours and Dimitres responses fixed the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**One obvious problem**:

```
  <a href="javascript:;"
  onmousedown="toggleDiv(<xsl:value-of select="position()"/>');"> 
<xsl:attribute name="onmousedown">
   <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
```

**Must be**:

```
   <a href="javascript:;"/>

   <xsl:attribute name="onmousedown">
    <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
   </xsl:attribute>
```

The reason for this problem is that markup (elements) is not allowed as value of an attribute in any well-formed XML document.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
<![CDATA[
  javascript code here
]]>
```

Everything inside it is totally ignored by any self-respecting XML parser.

Answer (score 0):

How about putting your JavaScript and CSS into external .js and .css files and using appropriate HTML tags to reference them?

Comment: For the purposes of this solution one single file works better than multiple files. This is meant to support a process and not exactly something I want to bloat out with extra files. Thanks.